# Graph. Adjacencies foreach iteration

Tags: c#, graph, foreach, ienumerable, enumerator

I am designing a Graph class (both list and matrix implementations). I have to provide method such as `GetAdjacencies(int vertex)`.

In the first moment I thought of returning `IEnumerable` and that way I will be able to iterate through the result using `foreach` statement. But in the next moment, I realized it is horrible solution because new list must be created each time `GetAdjacencies(int vertex)` occurs.

Next I thought of returning `Enumerator`, but that way I can't iterate through the result using `foreach` statement. However efficiency is much better (I will implement many graph algorithms and I am really interested in optimization).

Could you tell me what is the right way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create new list each time the method is called. Use iterator blocks for instance:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetAdjacencies(int vertex)
{
    foreach (int i in adj[vertex])
        yield return i;
}
```

I don't know how exactly the graph is represented in your code, so the details of getting adjacencies list may vary.

Comment: Your code compiles :) So now I doubt I understand the meaning of `yield` keyword. Could you explain me what it does in the current context?

Comment: See here for example: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx

Comment: And [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx) are the gory details :)